# Program to traverse a m*m matrix in inverse s order

Tags: c

EXAMPLE:

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I need the following output for the program:

```
1 2 3 4 8 7 6 5 9 10 11 12 16 15 14 13.


 for(i=0;i<m;i++)
 {
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        print("%d",a[i][j]);
    }
 }
```

this piece of code prints the matrix in an array but i need it in inverse s order as it is a part of my project .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please rad the [About] page soon. To format text as 'code' (in fixed width font), write the data as you want it to appear, then select it and use the **`{}`** button over the edit box to indent it.  We will help people who've made an honest effort at solving a problem, but we don't normally do homework questions for you without some evidence that you've tried (which means you show the code).  A start would be 'how do you print the first row'?  How might you print the second row?  Then can you generalize that to print the Nth and N+1th rows?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't show minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: How are you storing the "matrix", as a 2d array or as a flat allocation that you are accessing as `[(y*width) + x]`?

Comment: Show us code you've attempted.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the issue being encountered by the OP is not evident.

Comment: In order to perform embedding data into pixel values taken in a form of matrix i need to traverse the m*m matrix in a inverse s order as per the algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    if(i%2 == 0)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int j = m-1; j >= 0; j--)
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    if(i%2==1){    
        for(j=m-1;j>=0;j--){
             print("%d",a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    else{
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
             print("%d",a[i][j]);
    }
}
```